# How to visualize Velodyne VLP-16 lidar data through wifi?

Tags: router, routing, ethernet, port-forwarding, virtual-server-2005-r2

I have a lidar that transfers data through ethernet and we can visualize it using veloview. i like to do the same with the help of router in-between i.e. the router will be connected with the ethernet cable coming from the lidar and that router will be connected to my laptop using wifi. The web interface of the lidar can be opened on `192.168.1.201` but in the veloview i cannot see any data coming from the lidar.Default port for Veloview`2368`
This is my [ethernet config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ypWdm.png).
This is details I get from wireshark when I visualize data [through ethernet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FbKrF.png) in Veloview.
This is details I get from wireshark, if I connect [through wifi](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0uFVu.png), but couldn't visualize on veloview.
[What Virtual server settings can I give in here?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/swqRO.png)
This is the [lidar web interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h5Vmf.png) that works both on ethernet and wifi.
This is the [wifi config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SOVoM.png).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.